Django - Custom Translation for Django automatically generated messages
In a django project, how do I access the messages generated automatically by django?
After implementing internationalization it seems some messages have been left our of the translation. IN particular those generated as part of the authentication process.
Amongst the different messages I am trying to access is this one: The two password fields didn’t match..
I thought I could:

override the existing UserCreationForm in the views
write the sentence in english I want to override
use from django.utils.translation import gettext as _ to capture it in the
.po file.

It feels overly complicated for what I am trying to achieve. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?
forms.py:
class  RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    
    def clean_email(self):
        if User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("the given email is already registered"))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #iterate over form fields and set label to false
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.label = False

views.py
def register_user_form(request):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            age_group = form.cleaned_data.get('age_group')
            # check if userprofile with same username already exists
            user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
                user=user, defaults={'age_group': age_group})
            if not created:
                user_profile.age_group = age_group
                user_profile.save()

            user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            for error in list(form.errors.values()):
                messages.error(request, error)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return redirect('template.html', {'form': form})

